# Git add files from ignored folder as if they were in root

Tags: git

I have an app living in `develop` branch and bundled using webpack into `dist/` folder. I also have `gh-pages` detached branch.

I want to take files from `dist/` in develop and add them to `gh-pages` as if those files were in root. The goal is I want builded app to be uploaded to GitHub pages.

`dist/` folder is in `.gitignore` file

I tried something like `git add -f dist/ :/`, however this will add all ignored files.

Therefore the question is how do I add and commit files from ignored `dist/` folder as if those files were in project root?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that this is not a git's responsibility. In such case, I just remove all files except `dist` (and node_modules, etc) from root and `cp -r dist/* .`,  then add new/modified files to stage list and commit them.

Comment: @Microfed that's what I do right now, but on the other side when you switch back to develop branch you will have those extra files from root around

Comment: Hm...actually, you shouldn't see these files in another branch after you commit them in gh-pages branch.